# Representative of Imam Mahdi (wilayet al fakih)

Tags: shia-sunni, imam-mahdi

The definition of "welayat el fakih" from wikipedia:

> ولاية الفقيه هي مصطلح سياسي ظهر حديثا في الفقه الشيعي. حيث يعتبرها فقهاء ولاية وحاكمية الفقيه الجامع للشرائط في عصر غيبة الإمام الحجة، حيث ينوب الولي الفقيه عن الإمام الغائب في قيادة الأمة وإقامة حكم اللّه على الأرض.

What matter to me the most when they said:' حيث ينوب الولي الفقيه عن الإمام الغائب في قيادة الأمة '.
My question: How someone can know and be sure that he is the representative of the imam Mahdi ?  Why through history (as far as I know) there wasn’t a big role for the wilayat al fakih where he effects a nation and spreads the proficy.

> أما أهل السنة والجماعة فيرون أنه لا وجود لمثل هذه الولاية لا في القرآن ولا في السنة ولم يفعلها لا الصحابة ولا غيرهم ولكنهم يعترفون بخلافة إسلامية تدير جميع أراضي المسلمين بالتوحيد وعبادة الله وحده.

For the Sunni Muslim they believe that a caliphate exists . So where is he? What is the conditions of that khalifa and what its proficy .

Comment: Closing this question as unclear because multiple question are being asked in one. Please try to [edit] the question and make it specific and focused. And while you at it try to quote the English text of the definitions.

Answer (score 3):

> My question: How someone can know and be sure that he is the
>   representative of the imam Mahdi ?

Wali Faqih has some required term that are set by Ahl al Bayt and specially Imam Mahdi (a.s.) before start of his occultation. So the required terms are known. And the Wali Faqih himself does not select himself. It is said that Imam Mahdi a.s. selects the best case for Wilayat Faqih and tells this to some scholars that are in relation with him and so scholars select that person Wilayat Faqih.

> why through history (as far as I know) there wasn’t a big role for the
>   wilayat al fakih where he effects a nation and spreads the proficy.

This is not true. Imam Khomeini is the best example of Wilayat Faqih. He was leader of Iran Islamic revolution which was a big historical change in state of Iran and also affecting all Islamic nations in the world. Before him some other scholars undertook the position of Wali Faqih but because of different political issues specially the power of British colonialism over Islamic nations they could not establish an Islamic state. But still they used the Wali Faqih authorizations as much as they could. One example of Wali Faqih before Imam Khomeini is Mirza Shirazi who was seeking establishment of independent Islamic state.

> For the Sunni Muslim they believe that a caliphat exists. So where
>   is he? What is the conditions of that khalifa and what its prophecy .

I am not a Sunni Muslim. They themselves should answer this. But according Shia Islam currently the only legitimate Caliph is Imam Mahdi (a.s). but he is at occultation by will of Allah and during his occultation the Wali Faqih takes his position and performs the duties of Islamic leader and Caliph.

**Reference and more study:**

[Islamic Government: Governance of the Jurist](http://www.al-islam.org/islamic-government-governance-of-jurist-imam-khomeini)

Comment: what do you mean by 'to some scholars that are in relation with him' who are they, how they communicate with Imam el Mahdi . and I was asking if there are a wali fakih before Imam el khomeini

Comment: @Moudiz because we are at times of occultation so relation with Imam Mahdi a.s. should remain secret. but finding them is not hard. they do not disclose their relation publicly. but disclose it to their close friends. anyway those scholars have a leadership role among Muslims and they can guide people for selecting the best case for Wilayat Faih. they simply see and talk him. I improved answer for before him.