# What is hujjat? Who is hujjat of Allah now?

Tags: shiism, shia-imam, imam-mahdi, hojjat

Is this what 'hujjat' is?

> in every era there must be one person to guide people and to help them obtain spiritual growth and fulfill their responsibilities towards their society.

Who is 'hujjat' now? Is Imam Mahdi Allah's hujjat now?

And a similar question, what does "Wali Faqih (ولایة الفقیه)" mean? Is it something same like Hojjat or 'different?' If different, who is 'Wali Faqih (ولایة الفقیه)' now?

*(Shia viewpoint only)*

Comment: [Answer](http://islam.stackexchange.com/a/11882/11938) for Walih Faqih

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With respect to the meaning of Hujjah, it could be said that the word 'Hujjah' would be applied to the thing (matter) which we can **infer or argue** to it (as a brief description). (Read [More...](http://www.rohani.ir/istefta-484.htm) but source not in English)

The word "hujjah" has been used in different occasions in the holy Qur'an at verses like [4:165](http://quran.com/4/165) and [8:149](http://quran.com/8/149).

---

But in context to Shia Imams,

> **Hujjat means proof or demonstration**. When used in reference to Imams, it is to point to their status as being living signs of Allah or His proofs. In Shia traditions, there are many references to Imams by the concept of 'Hujjah.' In fact, Muhammad Kulayni titled his fourth hadith collection about the subject of Divinely-appointed authorities and Imam al-Mahdi as the "Book of the Proof" or Kitab al-Hujja (Credits: infatuated [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/23233/who-is-hojjat-who-is-allahs-hojjat-now#comment41784_23283))

---

Shia Islam believe **Hazrat Mahdi (Imam Zaman) is considered as the last Hojjah of Allah.** That’s why he (Imam Zaman) is famous as Hojjat-ibn-al-Hasan.  (Bahar-al-Anvar, Volume25, H6 and Volume97, Page 343.)

Davood ibn Qasem quoted I heard from the tenth Imam (Imam Ali al-Naqi (Hadi a.s.)) that was declaring:

> «الخَلَفُ مِنْ بَعْدِی الحَسَنُ فَكَیفَ لَكُمْ بِالْخَلَفِ مِنْ بَعْدِ
>   الخَلَفِ فَقُلتُ لِمَ جَعَلَنِی اللّهُ فِداكَ فَقَالَ: اِنَّكُم لا
>   تَرَوْنَ شَخْصَهُ وَلایحِلُّ لَكُم ذِكْرُهُ بِاسمِهِ فَقُلتُ كَیفَ
>   نَذكُرُهُ فَقَال: قُولُوا الحُجَّةُ مِنْ آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ»؛(7)
>
> My successor is my son, Hasan. How will be your feeling concerning the
>   successor of my successor? I said “God sacrifices me, why? Since you
>   won’t be able to see him …, He declared: you call him *hojjat* from the
>   household of the Muhammad (pbuh). /  7-  كتاب الغیبة، ص 202، ح 169؛
>   كافی، ج 1، ص 328، ح 13

Furthermore, it (his name) has applied in majority of the narrations as “Al-Hojjat Men Ale Mohammad”   «الحُجَّةُ مِنْ آلِ مُحَمَّدٍ») / 8-  ر.ك: همان؛ شیخ صدوق، علل الشرایع، ج 1، ص 245؛ كمال الدین و تمام النعمة، ج 2، ص 648.

---

**Reference:**

- [www.tebyan.net](http://www.tebyan.net/newindex.aspx?pid=193948)

Comment: Yes. That is what it means "Argument" as far as I know. But how are people called as arguments. Not clear from your answer...

Comment: Would u pls state more regarding this sentence of you (that what you mean precisely) " But how are people called as arguments"

Comment: Qur'an says hojjat as argument, how can Hujjat be meant as "reason or proof which it could be feasible to persuade or repel the rival???" and how is that meaning applicable on people.

Comment: Uh-huh, let me edit my explanation regarding the meaning of Hujjah, subsequently you'll probably be persuaded (And Allah knows best), Since I assume I couldn't convey its precise meaning in translating in English. otherwise I'll illustrate you more..

Comment: @servant-of-Wiser, Hujjat means proof or demonstration. When used in reference to Imams, it is to point to their status as being living signs of Allah or His proofs. In Shia traditions, there are many references to Imams by the concept of 'Hujjah.' In fact, Muhammad Kulayni titled his fourth hadith collection about the subject of Divinely-appointed authorities and Imam al-Mahdi as the "Book of the Proof" or *Kitab al-Hujja*

Comment: yeah that is why put up this question for actually. How is Imam Mahdi "living signs of Allah or His proofs"???  @infatuated

Answer (score 0):

It refers to an indisputable entity which has nothing wrong in it.

- The messengers/Imams of Allah
- Our own wisdom

It is through our wisdom that we will be held accountable for our actions. By it we know killing is bad, thankfulness is good. So no one on judgement day could say oh God I didn't know killing was bad.
By our wisdom we know who is a fake prophet and who is not.
Without our wisdom we are no different from animals.

The only thing is if you sin your wisdom becomes clouded explaining why different people have different opinions. Also if you conclude without sufficient information then you are overreaching your wisdom.
So basically by overreaching or sinning a **person** can create mistakes using his **100% correct wisdom**